# Windows 2012 DNS server phase out

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dns-server

I've got a network with 3 AD servers that also run the DNS service.

We've got a project on to migrate from Windows DNS to a new turnkey DDI solution.

I'm going through everything I can think of and manually changing its DNS client configuration to point at the new IP addresses of the new servers.

What I want to do is convert the original 3 AD/DNS servers into Forward Only servers so they send all queries to the new DNS servers,  and log the inbound queries to them (so I can figure out what still needs to be changed).

I've not been able to find instructions on converting a Windows DNS server to only forward and not actually resolve queries itself.

It's a production system,  so I've got to be careful about what I do to it.  -  for example,  I can't change the IP address of the DC's.

Any ideas?

Comment: A long-running packet capture would help you sort out which clients still need to be configured.

Comment: Yeah,  doing that too.  I'd still like to be able to forward for the short term interim.

Comment: why not consume the old IP address when the new server is ready? -....wait a sec, forget I spoke!

Comment: Do you still want the servers to be domain controllers afterwards?

Comment: Yeah,  they've got to remain Domain Controllers,  which puts a bit of a fly in the ointment.  Otherwise, it might be easier to change the IP of the DC's.  I think that would break more stuff than fix.

Comment: I'm at a much earlier stage of a similar task - i was under the impression that so long as global forwarders were configured, and all AD DNS was correctly migrated upstream, i would then delete the zone(s) from AD. Backups & rollback plan obviously on standby. Are there any other concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up biting the bullet.

I removed the zones from the name servers,  and simultaneously swapped every client's resolver details for the new IP addresses.

Then I did the packet capture, and think I found all the sources of DNS requests.

Finally,  I configured global forwarders.

It's working well so far..

Comment: Oh... I thought you had other DCs also hosting the same AD-integrated zone that you wanted to keep that way.

Comment: Noop.  AD integrated DNS  is a pile of poop that doesn't scale, it turns out.

Comment: Hmmm well our opinions differ there, but that is a discussion for another time.

Comment: Well done. I'm keen to know if you encounter any unforseen issues

Comment: I'll let you know!